# Validation check Excluding VAT, VAT and Total giving error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
ExclBTW   BTW    Totaal
  NaN     NaN   750.0
```

I'm trying to do some validation checks on the ExcludingBTW (=VAT), VAT and Total.
The following code is used:

```
#validation check
df1.loc[:, ['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']] = df[['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(float))
df1['Totaal'] = df[['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']].\
                  apply(lambda x: x['Totaal'] if x['Totaal'] == (x['ExclBTW'] + x['BTW']) else np.nan, axis=1)
```

This is working fine when the values are filled ! However when having null values python gives me the following error:

```
    116 
    117 #validation check
--> 118 df1.loc[:, ['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']] = df[['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(float))
    119 df1['Totaal'] = df[['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']].\
    120                   apply(lambda x: x['Totaal'] if x['Totaal'] == (x['ExclBTW'] + x['BTW']) else np.nan, axis=1)

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Is there any way to work around this?
```

I've tried to fill the NaN's as such:

```
#df1['BTW'] = df1['BTW'].fillna(float(1))
#df1['ExclBTW'] = df1['BTW'].fillna(float(1))
#df1['ExclBTW'] = df1['ExclBTW'].fillna(df1['Totaal'])
```

Unfortunately this does not work !

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) per all columns and then [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
cols = ['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']
df1[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, erros='coerce'))

df1['Totaal'] = np.where(df['Totaal'] == df['ExclBTW'] + df['BTW'], df['Totaal'], np.nan)
```